# Segueing a view without Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode5

I'm trying to figure out how to preform transitions between different views just with code, without storyboard. For example, on a button press.

```
- (IBAction)nextClass
{
    // insert transition between views
}
```

I know this is possible, I was just wondering what the actual code would be to make this happen.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials out there.  But the real question is, why exactly do you want to do this?  Why do you need this as opposed to segues?

Comment: @nhgrif: I'm not using segues as I don't have a storyboard in my project, I'm simply trying to perform the same task with code.

Comment: ...but why aren't you using storyboards?

Comment: @nhgrif I'm not using Storyboards because I want to get experience developing for iOS without using Storyboards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% sure if I am understanding your question correctly, but I think you can just say:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]
                          initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The name "ViewController" after initWithNibName should be the name of the .xib file that contains the UI for ViewController.  Let me know if this is what you are looking for!

**EDIT:**

Mungbeans brings up a good point.  If you are using a navigation controller, you should say:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]
                          initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: Or if you are using a navigation controller: [[self.navigationController] pushViewController: yourVC animated:YesOrNoWhateverYouWant];